# Is it possible to rename and block built-in functions temporarily?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wish to temporarily rename a built-in symbol and use it with different name while block the main name of this symbol. For example, I wish the following code to print only "2" but not "1" and "3":

```
Block[{print = Print, Print}, Print[1]; print[2]; Print[3];]
```

In really the above code prints nothing.

Is it possible to make `print` working inside such code while completely block symbol `Print`?

Solutions like

```
With[{Print = f, print = Print}, Print[1]; print[2]; Print[3];]
```

are not suitable since `Print` is not really blocked inside such code.

The question appeared while [thinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772277/the-logic-of-message-internals) on a way to disable tracing of `Message` internals.

Comment: Alexey, you do find the difficult questions.

Comment: And what if you use Hold instead of f? Does that not block Print (but not print) correctly?

Comment: @István, now it seems clear what you meant.  The problem is that `With` only replaces explicit instances of a symbol, while `Block` temporarily replaces the symbol for all calls within the Block, even those that are hidden.

Comment: You are not the only one who would like this functionality. In my fourth post in this thread, http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/a39d99bc1470bb3c, I described a hypothetical function `Unblock` which would do exactly what you want. Ideally, it would work in concert with `Block`, allowing many levels of nesting of blocking and un-blocking. Unfortunately, AFAIK, there is no built-in `Unblock` - like function. I'd be happy to learn that I am wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not very clean, but I believe it is serviceable.

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Print},
  Unprotect[Print];
  Print[x__] := Null /; ! TrueQ[$prn];
  print[x__] := Block[{$prn = True}, Print[x]];
  Print[1]; print[2]; Print[3];
]
```

---

If it is not acceptable to have the function replaced with `Null` in the return, you may need to use something like:

```
func[x__] := Hold[func[x]] /; ! TrueQ[$prn];
```

Followed by a `ReleaseHold` after the Block.

Or:

```
func[x__] := zz[x] /; ! TrueQ[$prn];
```

and then follow the Block with: `/. zz -> func`

Comment: Another instantiation of Todd's toolbag trick! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656). I do miss the $inMsg part ;-(  It's like the cube pal in Portal

Comment: Yep, that's the one. Forgot his name.

Comment: *Confess!*  Where did you learn about _Internal`InheritedBlock_ ??

Comment: @belisarius one of [Alexey's own Toolbag posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5686710#5686710), learned from Daniel Lichtblau.